# How do I write a regular expression that matches two patterns in any order?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to validate passwords in Ruby, with the requirement that they must contain at least one letter (`/[a-z]{1,}/`) and one number (`/\d{1,}/`). But these can occur in any order within the string. Can I do this in a single regexp?

```
'aa' => should not match
'99' => should not match
'a9' => should match
'9a' => should match
```

These *don't* work:

```
'9a' =~ /[a-b]{1,}\d{1,}/  <= no match
'a' =~ /[a-b]{1,}|\d{1,}/  <= match
```

Unfortunately I can't find something like a `&` (AND) operator corresponding to the `|` (OR) operator Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)/
```

Comment: -1, sorry: that requires the letter to precede the digit. I'm guessing you probably meant to write something like `/(?=.*?[a-z]).*?\d/i` (with a forward look-ahead assertion)?

Comment: I was editing it and took it out by accident. Its back in now

Comment: @OmarJackman I think you do not need the non-greedy operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
'9a' =~ /[a-z].*\d|\d.*[a-z]/
```

But I'd probably just bite the bullet and write it as two regexes:

```
'9a' =~ /[a-z]/ && '9a' =~ /\d/
```

**Edited to add:** Alternatively, from my comment to Omar Jackman's answer, you can write:

```
'9a' =~ /^(?=.*?[a-z]).*?\d/
```

using a zero-width *positive lookahead assertion* `(?=...)`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for all your cases:

`([a-zA-Z]+\d+|\d+[a-zA-Z]+)`

I also added uppercase letters since you didn't specify lowercase only.